# FInd index of an element in sorted array, if not found, print index where it should be inserted

Tags: c, arrays, loops, sorting, search

Print the index of the target element being searched in a sorted array. If the element is not found print the index where it should be inserted keeping the array sorted.

I wrote this program in C, but cannot understand where I went wrong, it is not working as expected.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int n,t,i,k=0,l=0;
        int arr[50];
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }
        scanf("%d",&t);
        // Array size should be less than 50
        if(n>50){
                printf("Array size exceeded");
                return 0;
        }
        //Check array is sorted and has no duplicates
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
                if(arr[i] == arr[i+1])
                        k++;
                if(arr[i] > arr[i+1])
                        l++;
        }
        if(k!=0){
                printf("No duplicates allowed");
                return 0;
        }
        if(l!=0){
                printf("Array must be sorted");
                return 0;
        }
        //Find element index or print where it should be inserted
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(arr[i] == t){
                        printf("%d",i);
                        return 0;
                }
                if(arr[i] > t){
                        printf("%d",i);
                        return 0;
                }
                else{
                        printf("%d",n+1);
                        return 0;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Since your array is sorted, why don't you use the binary search algo?

Comment: Check the value of `n` *before* you start reading in values to your array.

Comment: the `for` loop at the end does not do what you want

Comment: Binary search is a very good opinion. Thanks for that. Ok I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what your issue is is that you always print and return after your first iteration of your final loop. I can't be sure as I don't know which input you are giving, the output you are getting and the expected output

Try changing

```
    //Find element index or print where it should be inserted
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(arr[i] == t){
                    printf("%d",i);
                    return 0;
            }
            if(arr[i] > t){
                    printf("%d",i);
                    return 0;
            }
            else{
                    printf("%d",n+1);
                    return 0;
            }
    }
```

To

```
    //Find element index or print where it should be inserted
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(arr[i] == t){
                    printf("%d",i);
                    return 0;
            }
            if(arr[i] > t){
                    printf("%d",i);
                    return 0;
            }
    }
    printf("%d",n+1);
    return 0;
```

The reason for this is that if the first element in your array is less the t, n+1 will be printed, regardless of the other elements.
Also, you may be wanting to print a new line character after everything else so add `\n` to the end of your first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your logic in else statement of last loop.

Correct Code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,t,i,k=0,l=0;
    int arr[50];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    scanf("%d",&t);
    // Array size should be less than 50
    if(n>50||n<=0){
            printf("Array size exceeded");
            return 0;
    }
    //Check array is sorted and has no duplicates
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            if(arr[i] == arr[i+1])
                    k++;
            if(arr[i] > arr[i+1])
                    l++;
    }
    if(k!=0){
            printf("No duplicates allowed");
            return 0;
    }
    if(l!=0){
            printf("Array must be sorted");
            return 0;
    }
    //Find element index or print where it should be inserted
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(arr[i] == t){
                    printf("%d",i);
                    return 0;
            }
            if(arr[i] > t){
                    printf("%d",i);
                    return 0;
            }
            else{
                    printf("%d",i+1);
                    return 0;
            }
    }
}
```

Suggestion - Use binary search for sorted arrays.

Comment: You leave the check on array size until far too late; you should check that it is in range before you start reading values into it.  You should arguably check that the size is neither negative nor zero, too.  Your final loop is still flaky.  It only checks `arr[0]` before terminating.